# Is there an online, free, hosted solution to test and monitor Platform events outside of Salesforce?

Tags: platform-event, streaming-api

So, I am trying to test Platform events outside of Salesforce. I know it can be checked with PE Triggers. But I wanted to check it outside.
So, is there a tool or utility to test PE outside Salesforce just like we have for outbound messages.

Note:

1. I have tried Workbench but subscription doesn't work.
2. Checked this link: It doesn't work.
   [Not able to view platform events on workbench](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/208428/not-able-to-view-platform-events-on-workbench/215608)
3. Checked this as well. It also doesn't work.

Please try to give complete tested answer/approach as I have already searched & tried on workbench for hours before posting this question.

Comment: many middleware platforms can subscribe to Platform Events; check to see if your company is already licensing one.

Comment: Thanks but i was looking for any free hosted solution, i came across lot of blogs to build by yourself. But just wanted to check with community.

Comment: Wanted to check with community first. But it seems there is nil till now :p

Answer (score 4):

You can use, in theory, any client that implements the CometD library. Salesforce has [a guide on how to subscribe to platform events from outside the platform, using Java](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/code_sample_java_client_intro.htm).

If you search for "cometd library" online, you can find other implementations, such as [this one in Python](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/salesforce-streaming-client).

It is not likely that you will find a free hosted solution, since you basically need a computer to maintain a connection with Salesforce all the time with an HTTPS connection to listen for events (and CPU time costs money on any cloud provider).

Comment: Hi Renato, Thanks for your comment. But as mentioned, I was searching for any existing online utility (just like we have for outbound messages).

Comment: @RajendraSinghNagar Its not likely that you will find a free hosted solution today because of CPU costs. To listen to events you basically need a server to be up and running all the time, connected with the event publisher. I've edited my answer to add this part.